# Best way to start JBoss AMQ broker Artemis on JDK10

Tags: activemq-artemis, jboss-amq

Trying to start JBoss AMQ on JDK 10 and was getting 
`Unrecognized VM option 'UseFastAccessorMethods'`

I removed this option from `artemis-profile` and it works fine now.
Is there any better option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any better option.  That VM option has already been removed upstream in the Apache ActiveMQ Artemis project via [ARTEMIS-1449](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARTEMIS-1449).  This change will be included in a future version of Red Hat AMQ.

Comment: The link you have provided describes different solution (adding JAVA_ARGS=" --add-modules java.xml.bind [...]). Which option would you recommend to go for?

Comment: There were several commits associated with JDK 9+ compatibility related to that JIRA.  See https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=activemq-artemis.git;a=blobdiff;f=artemis-cli/src/main/resources/org/apache/activemq/artemis/cli/commands/etc/artemis.profile;h=5f83be8940fac603fab4b800e28c8974adf3eaea;hp=7f53c9959e37b30117275cc1677ee08d1244e72b;hb=67ee34d;hpb=94c34b7ed9345a4be4948a52ff3a177b270cd0e6 which removes the VM argument in question.  I was simply referencing the JIRA to demonstrate that your solution was already adopted in the code-base.

Answer (score 0):

That version of the Artemis Broker is built and tested to work on JDK 8 and as such the scripts and other supporting bits are designed around that.  If you want to use it on a platform that it isn't supported on then you will likely need to customize it to get things running.

Comment: Could you please ellaborate on customizing?

Comment: I believe "customizing" here refers to modifying scripts and/or configuration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. I did not expect such generalized answer, so pardon my additional questions.